# How do you declare revenues from YouTube earnings in the USA if you are a minor?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, minor

You are under 18 making thousands of $$ with your videos.

Can you declare them?

Comment: you need to add a country tag as this may well differ between tax regimes but in general you have to declare income. Whether a minor does this themself or it is a guardian's duty to do so is the real question.

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had. Posted so many questions today my head is spinning.

Comment: Not only can you, but you must pay income tax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive a 1099-MISC from YouTube, that tells you what they stated to the IRS and leads into most tax preparation software guided interviews or wizards as a topic for you to enter.  Whether or not you have a 1099-MISC, this [discussion from the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Reporting-Miscellaneous-Income) is pertinent to your question.

You could probably elect to report the income as a royalty on your copyrighted work of art on Schedule E, but see this note: "In most cases you report royalties in Part I of Schedule E (Form 1040). However, if you ... are in business as a self-employed writer, inventor, artist, etc., report your income and expenses on Schedule C or Schedule C-EZ (Form 1040)."

Whether reporting on Schedule E or C is more correct or better for your specific circumstances is beyond the advice you should take from strangers on the internet based on a general question - however, know that there are potentially several paths for you.

Note that this is revenue from a business, so if you paid for equipment or services that are 100% dedicated to your YouTubing (PC, webcam, upgraded broadband, video editing software, vehicle miles to a shoot, props, etc.) then these are a combination of depreciable capital investments and expenses you can report against the income, reducing the taxes you may owe.  If the equipment/services are used for business and personal use, there are further [guidelines from the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000208623) as to estimating the split. These apply whether you report on Sch. E, Sch. C, or Sch C-EZ.

Quote:

"Self-Employment Income

It is a common misconception that if a taxpayer does not receive a Form 1099-MISC or if the income is under $600 per payer, the income is not taxable. There is no minimum amount that a taxpayer may exclude from gross income.

All income earned through the taxpayer’s business, as an independent contractor or from informal side jobs is self-employment income, which is fully taxable and must be reported on Form 1040.

Use Form 1040, Schedule C, Profit or Loss from Business, or Form 1040, Schedule C-EZ, Net Profit from Business (Sole Proprietorship) to report income and expenses. Taxpayers will also need to prepare Form 1040 Schedule SE for self-employment taxes if the net profit exceeds $400 for a year. Do not report this income on Form 1040 Line 21 as Other Income.

Independent contractors must report all income as taxable, even if it is less than $600. Even if the client does not issue a Form 1099-MISC, the income, whatever the amount, is still reportable by the taxpayer.

Fees received for babysitting, housecleaning and lawn cutting are all examples of taxable income, even if each client paid less than $600 for the year. Someone who repairs computers in his or her spare time needs to report all monies earned as self-employment income even if no one person paid more than $600 for repairs."

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, you probably owe [Self Employment Tax](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Family/At-What-Income-Does-a-Minor-Have-to-File-an-Income-Tax-Return-/INF14178.html). The cutoff for tax on this is 400$. You will need to file a tax return and cover the medicaid expenses as if you were both the employer and employee.

> In addition, if he earns income from self-employment, he may owe Self-Employment Tax, which means paying both the employee’s and employer's share of Social Security and Medicaid taxes. The trigger for Self Employment Tax has been $400 since 1990, but the IRS may change that in the future.

Also see the [IRS website.](http://www.irs.gov/Help-&-Resources/Tools-&-FAQs/FAQs-for-Individuals/Frequently-Asked-Tax-Questions-&-Answers/Filing-Requirements,-Status,-Dependents,-Exemptions/Filing-Requirements/Filing-Requirements-2)

So yes, you need to file your taxes. How much you will pay is determined by exactly how much your income is.

If you don't file, you probably won't be audited, however you are breaking the law and should be aware of the consequences.